# Android - SQLite выборка по отрезку времени

Tags: android, sqlite

Всем привет, есть приложение где в БД SQLite есть колонка "date" с типом "text" (не уверен что правильный тип) где хранится дата в формате 01.12.2016. Необходимо сделать выборку по отрезку времени. Например с 01.05.2016 по 01.12.2016. Найти по 1 дате не проблема, а как сделать выборку за отрезок времени?

Comment: Если возможно, то лучше сделайте тип ```INTEGER``` и храните таймштамп.

Comment: Это типа в не преобразованном виде? А выборку делать как? Больше  меньше числа INTEGER?

Comment: Ну да, ```timestemp``` это же обычное число, которое представляет количество секунд, которое прошло с 1.01.1970, поэтому в бд их можно хранить как число, и выборку соответственно делать через обычные условия сравнения больше меньше. Так же потом это число можно будет без проблем преобразовать в человекочитаемый формат для отображения пользователю

Comment: А из String в виде "01.01.2016"  - я могу получить каким-то образом число? Преобразовать в long (количество секунд)? 
timestemp  - это что? Я получаю с помощью System.currentTimeMillis() а дальше преобразую через SimpleDateFormat

Comment: timestamp это и есть то, что возвращает ```System.currentTimeMillis()```, только в милисекундах. По поводу преобразования, ищите, уже не один такой вопрос здесь задавали, или смотрите сами ```SimpleDateFormat```

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, не знаю как отметить его правильным. Я так понимаю надо использовать метод parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная информация непосредственно к выборке по диапазону не относится (кроме приведения к формату timestring), но будет весьма полезна при работе с датами в SQLite.

Для работы с датами в SQLite вам нужно привести эту дату к формату, который данная БД может обрабатывать - timestring вида YYYY-MM-DD [HH:MM:SS].

Далее, используя функции SQL (например `date()` или `strfdate()` )вы можете получить определенные значения для составления запросов или напрямую получиь определенные данные (в основном, сколько прошло времени). Официальная [документация по этому вопросу](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) и [перевод](https://bravikov.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-sqlite/) на русском для плохо читающих.

Кроме того, вы можете использовать формат timestamp (unixtime, количество секунд с 1970 года). При использовании этого формата вы должны в функцию `date()` добавить модификатор `unixepoch`, который указывает, что дата именно в timestamp, а не timestring. Данное решение дает такое преимущество, что помимо специальных функций SQLite, вы можете работать с датами, как с простым числом (чем больше число, тем больше времени\старше дата)

сам запрос на выборку по диапазону дат может быть таким:

```
select * from datetable where date between '2015-12-11' and '2016-12-11'
```

**UPD:**

Для преобразования из unixtime в "человеческий" вид даты используйте класс `SimpleDateFormat` (в данном примере данные берутся из колонки курсора с именем *date*):

```
long unixTime = cursor.getLong(getColumnIndex("date"));
Date date = new Date(unixTime*1000L); // переводим в формат Android (см. примечание)
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"); //шаблон для даты в текстовом виде - получится так: 26.12.2016
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+4")); //если требуется, устанавливаем таймзону
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
textView.setText(formattedDate); // выводим в текствью
```

Данный код вы можете разместить прямо в адаптере (и в любом другом классе) и данные из курсора (или любого другого источника данных) перед выводом на экран преобразовывать. Если вы используете один из стандартных адаптеров, например, `SimpleCursorAdapter`, то для реализации вывода вам нужно будет написать собственный кастомный адаптер на основе используемого (унаследоваться от него), который и будет выполнять данное преобразование.

**Примечание:** В Android классы работы с временем возвращают timestamp в **милисекундах**, а в SQLite функция `date()` принимает его в **секундах**, поэтому значение нужно преобразовать (умножить на 1000).

Comment: Если я сохраню в Unix, а потом с помощью SimpleCursorAdapter захочу вывести ее в ListView, как мне ее преобразовать в нужный формат даты? Адаптер берет значения непосредственно из БД.