# Работа с датами в SQLite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Как известно, типа данных даты в  SQLite нету.
Подскажите способ, как лучше всего работать с датами, если к примеру в приложении нужно реализовывать такие функции, к примеру, как выборка покупок в определенный день, или выборка покупок за некоторый диапазон времени.
Я правильно понимаю, что сделать такую выборку на стороне базы данных, обычным запросом - не получится? Т.е. мне нужно считать все покупки, привести даты в нужный вид и обрабатывать уже в java-коде?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602127/177345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Традиционным способом является хранение даты в виде строки [в формате ISO8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
 "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"
```

В таком формате с ним умеет работать и сам SQLite - в частности `between`:

```
SELECT date FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-02-01"
```

ну и Java тоже умеет работать с таким форматом даты.

Comment: Ваш пример запроса для случая, если дата хранится в базе в виде строки? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, все верно - именно так, но только если формат даты соответствует маске `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS`

Comment: А Вы с регистром ничего не перепутали? YYYY, к примеру должно быть yyyy и MM во времени выдает месяц, а должно быть mm, что бы были минуты. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Вы когда-нибудь читаете документацию? [RTFM](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: я имею ввиду, что в java такой шаблон "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS" не работает.

Comment: (facepalm) Речь не шла о Java. Речь шла о SQLite, к тому же какое имеет отношение шаблон к форматированию вывода `SimpleDateFormat` - там совсем другие правила

Comment: Просто Вы написали, что java, тоже умеет работать с таким форматом даты. Под шаблоном я имею в виду формат даты в SimpleDateFormat. Может не правильно выразился, за это извиняюсь.

Comment: Имелось ввиду, что Java умеет парсить/генерить такой формат строки, но паттерн форматирования вывода там делается по другому. Читайте документацию к [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Да-да, я с Вами согласен. Поэтому собственно у меня и возник вопрос, что в java коде дата хранится в одном формате, а в sqlite - в другом. Получается перед вставкой даты в базу, её еще раз нужно переформатировать для понятного sqlite формата.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего сохранять дату в `long` в миллисекундах. С ними проще работать

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то, что я хотел узнать.

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин формат *timestamp* предложенный в этом ответе действительно удобнее текстового представления даты из другого ответа. С ним намного проще работать, некоторые операции будут выполняться существенно быстрее и его можно легко преобразовать в **любой текстовый вид** для вывода на экран, причем с учетом текущей локали. Подробнее смотрите ссылку на ответ под вопросом.

Comment: @pavlofff я вот не совсем понял в примере по Вашей ссылке, там в запросе between дата в виде '15-12-2017' . Но если в базе дата хранится в формате int как оно этот between обработает

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин при работе с датами (при вводе даты) получаете ее в формате *timestamp* и передаете в запрос полученные числа. и класс `Date` и класс `Calendar` возвращают дату в таком формате

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин timestamp это дата в миллисекундах. Соответственно вы можете сделать нужный вам запрос 'SELECT date FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "число 1" AND "число2"'

Comment: pavel163 Я правильно понимаю ? - В Вашем запросе "число 1" и "число 2" это дата в формате timestamp. А что бы отправить запрос к БД эти самые 2 числа я должен преобразовать к формату timestamp непосредственно в java-коде ДО обращения к БД?

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин да