# Выбрать задания за сегодня sql lite

Tags: android, sqlite

В базе есть столбцы `startDate` и `endDate`.

В этих полях хранится время назначения и срок выполнения.
Например: 10.04.2017 13:00:00,12.05.2017 18:00:00 соответственно (тип поля `text`).

Как сделать выборку по заданиям у которых срок выполнения сегодня? 
Т.е. выборку по след логике: `where endDate>=текущая дата 00:00:00 AND endDate<=текущая дата 23:59:59`

Один из вариантов который я пробовал, но не работает

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where startDate is null OR strftime('%s', startDate) > strftime('%s','2017-06-15 23:59:59')
```

Comment: Работает если формат времени в базе yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, а у меня dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss ;(

Comment: в sql lite нету типа поля DateTime -> там есть поле text т.е. string.
из-за этого так получилось что туда время пишут в формате dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss . Может есть возможность sql запросом менять формат?

Comment: Был невнимателен. Прошу пардону. Комменты не по делу удалил.

Comment: Для наименьшего количества проблем вам нужно [преобразовать свои даты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602127/177345) либо к ISO8601 (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss), либо к unixtime и работать с функциями, предоставляемыми самой SQLite, либо придумывать какие-то собственные костыли для обработки нестандартного формата даты через код, очевидно намного более медленные и неудобные.

Comment: как [преобразовать даты](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968618/sqlite-convert-dd-mm-yyyy-formated-string-to-date) в таблице SQLite

Comment: Остановился на изменении формата времени.
Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй привести даты к одинаковому виду

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where TO_DATE(startDate,'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss') = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: no such function: TO_DATE