# Получить текущую дату в миллисекундах из TimePickerDialog и DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть активити с двумя кнопками. Первая позволяет выбрать из календаря дату, вторая выбрать время. Это нужно, чтобы пользователь при добавлении записи в БД сам выбирал дату и время. Также есть `TextView`, в который выводится выбранная дата и время. С выбором даты проблем нет.. В БД есть таблица с полем date типа `Integer`, хочу в этом поле записывать выбранные пользователем дату и время в миллисекундах (читала что лучше хранить в таком виде, для удобства и быстроты выборки). Как я могу получить выбранную дату и время пользователем в миллисекундах в `timestamp`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calendar dateAndTime=Calendar.getInstance();
    TextView txtTest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtTest = findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
        Button btnTime2 = findViewById(R.id.btnTime2);
        Button btnDate2 = findViewById(R.id.btnDate2);

        //отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора времени
        btnTime2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, t,
                    dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
                    .show();
        });

        //отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора даты
        btnDate2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, d,
                    dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                    .show();
        });

        setInitialDateTime();
    }

    //установка обработчика выбора времени
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };

    //установка обработчика выбора даты
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };

    //установка начальных даты и времени
    private void setInitialDateTime() {

        txtTest.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,
                dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
                        | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
    }
}
```

Comment: для сохранения в базу: dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis()/1000L, так как андроид считает таймштамп в милисекундах, а sqlite в секундах. из бд в приложение соответственно наоборот, умножить на 1000. смотрите так же upd к [этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602127/177345)

Comment: Правильно ли я вам поняла что dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis()/1000L даст мне дату и время в секундах для SQLite? Не просто время или дату отдельно, а именно дату и время возвращает getTimeInMillis()?

Comment: да, таймштамп ([unix timestamp](https://yandex.ru/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Fru.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FUnix-%25D0%25B2%25D1%2580%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BC%25D1%258F)) это количество секунд (в sqlite) или милисекунд (в андроид) прошедших с 00:00 1 января 1970 года, классы Calendar или Date могут рассчитать из этого значения  "человеческую" дату и время. если для расчета таймштапа использовалась только дата, то время будет 00:00. соответственно из таймштампа можно получить отдельно дату или время или все вместе, в зависимости от используемых методов класса Calendar или форматирующей строки класса Date

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите календарь, установите нужную дату и время, а потом вызовите метод getTimeInMillis()

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myHours );
calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE, myMinutes );
...
long mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis()
```