# Получение TimeStamp при выборе даты и времени

Tags: android

Не могу найти понятный пример.. В активити есть `timepicker` и `datepicker`. Пользователь будет выбирать дату и время и в БД планируется хранить `timestamp`. Как это обычно реализуется?

Есть такой пример, но тут только таймштамп даты, а время получается не указано.

А у меня в активити есть две кнопки одна открывает окно для выбора даты, вторая для выбора времени и выбранные дату и время нужно перевести в таймштамп.

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        int y = year;
        int m = monthOfYear;
        int d = dayOfMonth;
        int dateMonth = monthOfYear + 1;
        int dateYear = year;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            //Тут храним дату в миллисекундах
            long epoch = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy").parse(m + "." + dayOfMonth + "." + year).getTime() / 1000;
            Log.d("DDDDDDDDD", epoch + "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setInitialDateTime();


    }
};
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1038429/11515 - очень похожий вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю что там пишут.