# Определять текущий день, неделю и месяц

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

Есть приложение и несколькими таблицами. В таблицу добавляются записи с указанием даты в `TimeStamp`.

```
mills = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
```

Далее требуется выводить в `RecyclerView` данные из таблицы добавленные за текущий день, за текущую неделю и месяц.

Например будет активити, где пользователь выберет фильтр "за текущий день" или "текущая неделя" или "текущий месяц" и будут выведены записи согласно выбранному фильтру

Подскажите пожалуйста как определять эти периоды?

Создание таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE `tab1` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `date`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `comments`  TEXT
);
```

Вот запрос создания таблицы. В поле date записываю как выше говорила `calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L`.

Comment: Ссылку на вопрос не поняла. Мне кажется что в том вопросе описано не то что мне нужно. У меня все выводится в TextView. У меня вопрос в том как определить текущий день, неделю и месяц. Т.е. при открытии активити я должна знать какой день, неделя или месяц

Comment: добавил ответ, это то что вы искали?

Comment: в SQLite есть инструменты для получения выборок, [связанных с временными промежутками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602127/177345). то есть вы составляете запрос и получаете выборку, например, за неделю до текущего дня

Comment: А можете объяснить пример. Например пользователь за 30.11.2019 добавил в течение дня несколько записей (допустим в 9:00 утра, 12:00 дня и 19:00 вечера), соответственно в поле date у них timestamp будет разный. Тоже самое пользователь добавил записи 01.12.2019. Но мне нужно вывести все эти записи по условию текущий день. в SQLIte какой запрос будет? Вот это не могу понять

Comment: посмотрите вот примеры https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504218/query-last-day-last-week-last-month-sqlite

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, но по ссылке не очень поняла. Вот в поле date у меня записано значение типа long (timestamp). В примере есть метод datetime('now', 'localtime'). Это что за метод? Как сделать например запрос для выборки данных за последнюю неделю?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date >= ????? AND date <= ?????? что писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

база данных SQLite имеет рад функций для работы с датами и временем, которые позволяют делать выборки по этим датам, времени или их промежуткам:

time() - время
date() - дата
datetime() - дата и время

и др. подробнее в [документации](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) ([перевод](https://bravikov.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-sqlite/))

функции принимают первым аргументом саму точку отсчета даты\времени:

now - текущая дата и время на момент запроса, так же можно указать любую другую дату в формате timestring (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

и ряд модификаторов:

Следующие модификаторы могут задавать смещение (+ или -):
NNN days - указать количество дней
NNN hours - количество часов
NNN minutes - количество минут
NNN.NNNN seconds - количество секунд и милисекунд
NNN months - количество месяцев
NNN years - количество лет

следующие модификаторы задают позицию времени:
start of month - начало месяца (первое число месяца)
start of year - начало года
start of day - начало дня (время 00:00)

weekday N - указывает на номер дня недели (0 - воскресение)
unixepoch - указывает, что время в первом аргументе задано в формате timestamp ( количество секунд с 1 января 1970 г.), должен указываться вторым аргументом, сразу за строкой даты и времени.
localtime - указывает, что в базе время задано в UTC и его надо преобразовать в локальное время и дату на устройстве
utc - указывает, что в базе время в локальном формате и его надо преобразовать в UTC.

Модификторы должны следовать в порядке перечисления в таблице по группам, за иключением unixepoch (который идет вторым). Так же заранее нужно определиться, в каком часовом поясе будет происходить работа со временем (в локальном или UTC) и соответственно сохранять в базу и делать запросы в одном формате, иначе использовать модификаторы localtime, utc если в базе и в запросах используются разные часовые пояса. О подробностях и нюансах использования модификаторов смотрите документацию.

Например, функция `datetime('now', 'localtime')` - это функция SQLite, которая возвращает время и дату,  в формате timestring (результатом работы этой функции будет строка вида YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). Модификаторы здесь указывают на то, какое именно время возвращать: now -первый аргумент, сама дата и время, с которой будет работать функция, здесь текущее время на момент запроса, localtime- время вернуть в часовом поясе, установленном на устройстве, на котором делается запрос.
Эта функция просто подставит строку с датой на свое место, соответствующее времени, указанном модификаторами. вы можете использовать этот результат, как считаете нужным: сравнивать, вычитать и т.п.

Теперь несколько запросов.

выборка за неделю:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now','-6 days') AND datetime('now');
```

- запрос вернет все записи из таблицы *tab1* в которых в столбце *date* время находится в промежутке между (BETWEEN) шестью днями от времени совершения запроса (now - время сейчас, - 6 days - отступить от него на 6 дней назад) и (AND) временем совершения запроса (now - сейчас)

Можно более короткое:

```
 SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date >= datetime('now','-6 days')
```

- все записи в которых в столбце *date* число больше или равно таймштампу времени запроса минус шесть дней.

выборка за текущий день:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of day') AND datetime('now');
```

- start of day - смещение на начало дня указанного первым аргументом даты и времени (у нас указано now - текущая дата и время на момент запроса)

на текущий месяц:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now');
```

- start of month - перейти к началу текущего месяца

выборка от начала прошлого месяца (на текущую дату этого ответа это будет с 1 ноября):

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month','-1 month') AND datetime('now');
```

- start of month - на начало текущего месяца указанной даты (у нас текущая дата запроса now), -1 month - на один месяц назад

на прошедший месяц (только на ноябрь по дате написания ответа):

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month','-1 month') AND datetime('now','start of month');
```

Если вы работаете только  с датами, без учета времени, то вместо datetime() можно использовать функцию date()

**UPDATE**

Для работы с временем, когда в базе хранится значение в формате timepstamp, перечисленные выше функции не используются, так как возвращают результат только в формате timestring (или я не нашел, как вернуть в формате timestamp). Для сравнения с таймштампом используем функцию `strftime()` с форматом возвращаемого значения %s (секунды от 1 января 1970 г., то есть нужный нам timestamp).

Соответственно, те же запросы из примеров выше при хранении в базе даты в формате timestamp будут:

за неделю:

```
 SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%s','now','-6 days') AND strftime('%s','now');
```

за текущий день:

```
 SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%s','now','start of day') AND strftime('%s','now');
```

за последний месяц:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE date BETWEEN strftime('%s','now','start of month') AND strftime('%s','now');
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь. Попробовала добавить запись. В поле date записывается значение timestamp = 1575486051. В Dao запрос такой SELECT SUM(summ) FROM costs WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'unixepoch', 'start of day') AND datetime('now', 'unixepoch') для подсчета суммы значений из поля summ, но почему-то выдает 0. Записи добавляются в БД это точно

Comment: Может быть неправильно записываю в поле data значение. Не могу понять в чем причина

Comment: Создала тестовую базу на ПК, добавила запись, где в поле date значение 1575547556, запросом SELECT * from tab1 where date BETWEEN date('now', 'unixepoch','start of month', 'localtime') and date('now','unixepoch', 'localtime') не выдает ничего!

Comment: смотрите **UPDATE** в конце ответа, теперь должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Получить день недели, месяц и все тому подобное можно таким способом:

```
Date date = // the date instance
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR); // год
calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // месяц
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // день
```

Номер недели можно получить так:

```
calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); // номер недели
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR) по номеру недели.

Comment: А как получить это в TimeStamp? В итоге мне нужно так: Например если пользователь выбрал фильтр "За неделю" вывести все записи где в таблице table1 поле date в промежутке от понедельника до воскресенья включительно в timestamp (т.е. date >= dat1 and <= dat2), где dat1 и dat2 это число типа long, которое содержит значение timestamp понедельника и воскресенья текущего месяца. Ну по такому же подобию за месяц и день

Comment: timestamp это системное unix время, оно у вас всегда есть))) просто нужно его отформатировать в нужном вам виде и все

Comment: в sqlite есть свои операторы работы со временем. нет необходимости получать их через java код