# Преобразование даты в строку android

Tags: java, android

При нажатии пользователем на TextView у меня появляется окно выбора даты, месяца и года в том же TextView.

```
  public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppDataBase myDB;
private TextView mDisplayDate;
public static final String TAG = "EditActivity";
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);
    mDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDates);
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(EditActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth, mDateSetListener, year, month, day);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        }
    };
```

Далее мне нужно записать параметры которые я заполняла в edit_layout в базу данных и вывести.

Все параметры которые я вводила ранее в EditText (они у меня типа float) у меня адекватно выводятся. Я их преобразовывала в строки следующим образом:

```
 public void setData(Dann dann) {
        tvVat.setText(String.valueOf(dann.getVat())); 
        tvOm.setText(String.valueOf(dann.getOm()));

}
```

Как мне в таком случае быть с датой которая прописывается в TextView?
Как мне ее преобразовать после записи в бд и вывести?

Comment: Даты в БД лучше хранить [в формате timestamp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602127/177345). Преобразовывать в этот формат и в читаемую дату для отображения на экране с помощью SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В onDateSet лучше сразу преобразовывать введенную дату в формат класса Date. Этот класс хранит в себе число миллисекунд, прошедших с 00:00 01.01.1970 +0UTC. Это же значение вы получаете через System.currentTimeMillis ().

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(0)); //чтобы часы и меньшие поля обнулились
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
long t = cal.getTime().getTime();
```

t - число, которое можно хранить в бд. Даты в бд вообще хранятся в числе секунд, а не миллисекунд, так что если поделите его на 1000, то из базы тоже можно будет работать с числом как с датой и делать селекты по году, например.

Получить строку для отображения в TextView можно так

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
String text = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: Подскажите. Я использую для хранения данных Room DataBase. Остальные данные (помимо даты) я прежде объявляла в своем классе, они были у меня типа - float. Сейчас мне нужно как раз таки записать в бд дату и потом ее вывести. Остальные данные я преобразовывала в строку таким образом:

public void setData(Dann dann) {
        tvVat.setText(String.valueOf(dann.getVat())); 
        tvOm.setText(String.valueOf(dann.getOm()));
}
Мне в этом класс нужно объявить дату, я так понимаю мне придется ее объявить целочисленной, т.е int.
А далее преобразовывать в строку тем образом как вы указали?

Comment: @Лидия только не int, а long. Если у вас рум - промто создаете поле иипа long и по мере необходимости с помощью календапя выводите как текст. Можно и как текст хранить, но тогда будут сложности с часовыми поясами и селектами по дате