# Как посчитать дату в формате string

Tags: android, дата, datepicker, calendar, datetimepicker

Мне нужно рассчитать возраст, ввести фильтр по датам и т.д. но я не понимаю как вообще переоброзовать теперь эту `"31 марта 2021 г., 05:18"` дату в формат даты. Я бы мог ввести его в формат SimpleDateFormat, но месяца имеют разные размеры данных. Вот так я записываю дату и иногда время мероприятия:

```
public void setDate() {
    new DatePickerDialog(Create_tournament.this, d,
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .show();
    setTime();
}

// отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора времени
public void setTime() {
    new TimePickerDialog(Create_tournament.this, t,
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true)
            .show();
}
// установка начальных даты и времени
private void setInitialDateTime() {


//Вот тут я просто присваиваю кнопке date значение выбранной даты и сохраняю в бд

    date.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(Create_tournament.this,
            dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
                    | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
}

// установка обработчика выбора времени
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};

// установка обработчика выбора даты
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDateTime();
    }
};
```

и я теперь не понимаю как теперь с этим работать

Comment: Для работы с датами очень удобно использовать библиотеку [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). На гитхаб есть версия для android. Общий смысл работы с датами в том, что вам сначала нужно выбрать удобный инструмент для их обработки, а потом писать под него код, а не сначала что то накостылить, а потом думать, что и как с этим можно сделать

Comment: Так же заранее стоит подумать о том, где все это хранить, лучшим вариантом будет одна из БД. Тогда стоит узнать, как эта БД работает с датами и использовать ее возможности, чтобы получать нужные данные через запросы к самой БД, они обрабатывают информацию в разы быстрее, чем это сделает Java через клиентский код и отдают только нужное (например записи в определенном диапазоне дат) [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/602127/177345)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что проблема в том, что некоторые даты имеют время, а другие - нет и и все это как то надо обрабатывать вместе? Самым простым решением будет обязать указывать время к дате принудительно (как, например, в google calendar) Если это не приемлемое решение, можно предложить писать время отдельно (и если его нет писать null). Из вашего вопроса не понятно, как вы собираетесь хранить эти данные, в случае с БД организовать такое будет несложно (добавить колонку к записи). При чтении проверять ее на null и если значение есть, добавлять к дате

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, попробую. Бд firebase и в каком бы формате я ему не передавал бы он возвращает строку...

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с датой и временем рекомендую использовать формат long, в миллисекундах. Сравнение, хранение и т.д.

```
public static long getMilliFromDate(String dateFormat) {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(dateFormat);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println("Today is " + date);
    return date.getTime();
}

public static String getTimeStamp(long timeinMillies) {
    String date = null;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"); // modify format
    date = formatter.format(new Date(timeinMillies));
    //System.out.println("Today is " + date);
    return date;
}
```